# Using jQuery on WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

This is my first ever experience with jQuery. My code to load in the jQuery is:

```
function load_sitekit_jquery ($hook) {
    //if( 'admin.php' != $hook )
       // return;
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sitekit', plugins_url('assets/sitekit.js', __FILE__) );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_sitekit_jquery' );
```

The script itself:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $( "div:contains('PageSpeed Insights')" ).css( "display", "none" );
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what you need to hide? a div?

Comment: Whats in your console? Any errors?

Comment: Are your script is load in admin?

Comment: @Kevin Yes i'm trying to hide a div by jQuery :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `enqueue` the `jQuery` inorder to use that. Please find the below code and replace your one with it.

```
function load_sitekit_jquery ($hook) {
    //if( 'admin.php' != $hook )
       // return;
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sitekit', plugins_url('assets/sitekit.js', __FILE__),array('jquery') );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_sitekit_jquery' );
```

Hope that will work for you.

Comment: Great it works for you, please upvote my answer too.